# Neo4j unable to delete database on FileSystem after shutdown

Tags: lucene, neo4j

- Given I first create a newEmbeddedDatabase("/my-path") with Neo4j 2.1.4
- And I create some nodes successfully (committing transactions)
- And I call shutdown() on my database
- When I attempt to delete "/my-path" (FileUtils.forceDelete(...))
- Then I consistently see this Java IOException:

**Unable to delete file "/my-path/scheme/label/lucene/_5.cfs"**

My hunch is that Neo4j does not properly destroy Lucene after calling shutdown, but am not sure. Looking for help. Thank you.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Never seen that issue before. Do you let the shutdown finish? What os? Would you mind setting up a sample project on github that reproduces the issue?